# Overlay view but still let underlying view receive events

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` which is take up the majority of the screen and at the bottom of the screen I have absolutely positioned a Image. What I want though is for the `FlatList`, which is below the absolutely position element, to still receive events (pan responder type in this case) I have tried by wrapping image in `<View>` and setting               `pointerEvents={'none'}` but that doesn't give me the result I want.

FWIW the use case is adding a slight white gradient which disappears into complete transparency. (thinking of using `react-native-linear-gradient` as an alternative.

```
      <View pointerEvents={'none'}>
        <Image
          pointerEvents={'none'}
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            height: 100,
            opacity: 0.8
          }}
          source={require('Project/assets/1.0/Screen1.0.2/bottom-gradient.png')}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes a parent will want to make sure that it becomes responder.
>   This can be handled by using the capture phase. Before the responder
>   system bubbles up from the deepest component, it will do a capture
>   phase, firing on*ShouldSetResponderCapture. So if a parent View wants
>   to prevent the child from becoming responder on a touch start, it
>   should have a onStartShouldSetResponderCapture handler which returns
>   true.

This is from documentation.I think it can solve your problem.if not you should checkout [full documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html).

Comment: Tried these, I'm putting it on the view that covers the image with false being returned for the pan responders but it is still capturing the event, will keep trying the different gesture handlers.